# Mysql Clone user account from database

Tags: mysql

I have a database with aproximately 200 tables. I want to clone a certain user-account in this database. Is this possible in mysql?

With cloning I mean to create a new user with the same 'settings' as the user with id 14.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all so far, like googling it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search reveals that you in fact can do this. There is a utility called " "mysql user clone", that lets you surprisingly clone a user for mysql.

If you check out [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqluserclone.html) I'm sure it provides you with great tips about how to use it, for instance, this quote:

> **EXAMPLES**
>   To clone joe as sam and sally with passwords and logging in as root on the local machine, use this command:

```
$ mysqluserclone --source=root@localhost \
  --destination=root@localhost \
  joe@localhost sam:secret1@localhost sally:secret2@localhost
# Source on localhost: ... connected.
# Destination on localhost: ... connected.
# Cloning 2 users...
# Cloning joe@localhost to user sam:secret1@localhost
# Cloning joe@localhost to user sally:secret2@localhost
# ...done.
```

Comment: i guess this is create a new databascse account is it ?

Comment: Did you even read the manual? For instance, literally in the first sentence it says "..to **create** one or more new user accounts with the same privileges as the original user". LITERALLY in the first sentence.

Comment: unfortunately it seems mysqluserclone is EOL, wonder how one is supposed to clone useraccounts now

Comment: wrote a similar utility to `mysqluserclone` below ^^

Answer (score 0):

since it appears @Nanne's approach, `mysqluserclone` is EOL / not supported by Oracle, i wrote a similar utility in PHP, usage:

```php
<?php
$db = new \PDO("mysql:host={$db_creds->dbhost};dbname={$db_creds->dbname};charset=utf8mb4;port=" . $db_creds->dbport, $db_creds->superuser_user, $db_creds->superuser_pass, array(
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
));
Mysqluserclone::clone_account($db, "original username", "cloned username");
```

and this part of the code may be of particular interest:

```php
        if (0) {
            echo "the following SQLs will clone this account:\n";
            echo implode("\n\n", $sqls_for_cloning) . "\n\n";
            die();
        }
```

- 

```php
<?php

class Mysqluserclone{
    private function __construct(){
        // by making this private, we ensure nobody try to instantiate us.
    }
    public static function clone_account(\PDO $db_connected_as_superuser, string $original_name, string $clone_name): void
    {
        $db = $db_connected_as_superuser;
        $sqls_for_cloning = [];
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user WHERE User = " . $db->quote($clone_name);
        if (0 !== $db->query($sql)->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_NUM)[0]) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("clone name already exists!");
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User = " . $db->quote($original_name);
        $current_user_one_for_each_host = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($current_user_one_for_each_host as $user_record) {
            $user_record["User"] = $clone_name;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO mysql.user SET \n";
            foreach ($user_record as $name => $val) {
                $sql .= self::mysql_quote_identifier($name) . " = " . self::mysql_quote_better($db, $val) . ",\n";
            }
            if (! empty($user_record)) {
                $sql = substr($sql, 0, - strlen(",\n"));
            }
            $sql .= ";";
            $sqls_for_cloning[] = $sql;
            $sqls_for_cloning[] = "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"; // YES this is required, otherwise you might get "grant not allowed to create accounts" errors
            $grants_raw_sql = 'SHOW GRANTS FOR ' . $db->quote($original_name) . '@' . $db->quote($user_record['Host']) . ";";
            try {
                $grants_raw = $db->query($grants_raw_sql)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            } catch (\Throwable $ex) {
                // somehow an empty grant table is a mysql error, not an empty rowset.. ignore it.
                $grants_raw = [];
            }
            $grants_raw = array_map(function (array $arr): string {
                if (count($arr) !== 1) {
                    throw new \LogicException("mysql layout for SHOW GRANTS has changed? investigate");
                }
                return $arr[0];
            }, $grants_raw);
            $original_name_as_identifier = self::mysql_quote_identifier($original_name);
            $clone_name_as_identifier = self::mysql_quote_identifier($clone_name);
            foreach ($grants_raw as $grant) {
                if (false === strpos($grant, $original_name_as_identifier)) {
                    throw new \LogicException("original grant without original name as identifier? investigate");
                }
                $grant = self::str_replace_last($original_name_as_identifier, $clone_name_as_identifier, $grant);
                $grant .= ";";
                $sqls_for_cloning[] = $grant;
            }
        }
        if (! empty($sqls_for_cloning)) {
            $sqls_for_cloning[] = "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;";
        }
        if (0) {
            echo "the following SQLs will clone this account:\n";
            echo implode("\n\n", $sqls_for_cloning) . "\n\n";
            die();
        }
        foreach ($sqls_for_cloning as $clone_sql) {
            $db->exec($clone_sql);
        }
    }
    private static function mysql_quote_identifier(string $identifier): string
    {
        return '`' . strtr($identifier, [
            '`' => '``'
        ]) . '`';
    }

    private static function mysql_quote_better(\PDO $db, $value): string
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return "NULL";
        }
        if (is_int($value)) {
            return (string) $value;
        }
        if (is_float($value)) {
            return number_format($value, 10, '.', '');
        }
        if (is_bool($value)) {
            return ($value ? "1" : "0");
        }
        return $db->quote($value);
    }

    private static function str_replace_last(string $search, string $replace, string $subject): string
    {
        $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
        }
        return $subject;
    }
}
```